# list box in applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to have users pick a department from a list box. And then that choice is stored in a variable as string.

How can I do this?

I have code written like this:

```
set deptList to {"dept1", "dept2", "dept3", "dept4"}

set dept_name to {choose from my list deptList}
```

when I run the script, I get this error.

> " doesn't understand
>   the "choose" message". number -1708 from

Am I writing this code wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close you had an errant 'my' which you do not need.

```
set deptList to {"dept1", "dept2", "dept3", "dept4"}

    set dept_name to {choose from list deptList}
```

Also you should pay attention to the colour code of the text. this will give you a clue as what the Applescript thinks the syntax is you have typed

[image]